# CSS styles not applying to buttons?

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following CSS:

```
/* START HEADER SETTINGS */
.header {
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 90%;
position: fixed;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #404040;
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
font-size: 30px;
}

#fundme {
padding-left: 2%;
font-size: 40px;
float: left;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

.header_buttons {
color: #fff;
background: #00cc66;
border-radius: 8px;
text-align: center;
margin: 5px;
padding: 10px;
}

.hb-4,
.hb-5 {
background: #00cc66;
float: right;
}

.logout {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background: #00cc66;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
border-radius: 8px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px;
float: right;
font-size: 30px;
}
/* END HEADER SETTINGS */
```

with the following pages:

page 1

```
<div class="header"><a id="fundme" href="https://fund.me">fund.me</a>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="button" name="profile" class="hb-4 header_buttons" value="Profile" />
        <input type="submit" name="logout" class="hb-5 header_buttons" value="Log Out" />
    </form>
</div> 

<div class="container">
the application will be shown here
<?php echo "<h4 class='alert'>" . $response . "</h4>"; ?>
</div>

</body>
```

page 2

```
<div class="header"><a id="fundme" href="https://fund.me">fund.me</a>
    <div class="hb-4 header_buttons"><a href="https://fund.me/signup.php">Sign Up</a></div>
    <div class="hb-5 header_buttons"><a href="https://fund.me/login.php">Log In</a></div>
</div> 

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <h1 class="credential_form">Sign Up</h1>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" class="credential_form" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" /><br /><br />
        <input type="text" name="email" class="credential_form" id="email" placeholder="Email" /><br /><br />
        <input type="password" name="password" class="credential_form" id="password" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="credential_submit" value="Submit" /><br /><br />
    </form>
    <?php if(isset($response)) echo "<h4 class='alert'>" . $response . "</h4>"; ?>
</div>  

</body>
```

It works fine on the second page, but the styling for the buttons in the header is messed up on the first page.

They're both using the same class, the only difference is that the first page uses buttons while the second uses link.  However, I don't see why that should matter for this styling.

Is there a reason the styling isn't identical for buttons?

Comment: The styling isn't identical because you are not clearing out the default styling of the inputs

Comment: How do I do that? I thought CSS would override default stylings.

Comment: It does, but you did not cancel out all the default styling for the inputs in your CSS. Look into a [form CSS reset](https://gist.github.com/anthonyshort/552543)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same class, but on different elements. You have `input[type=submit]`, `input[type=button]` and `div`s with `a` tags.

Each of those elements has different default styles and so you will need to adjust your css to reset/override those defaults

Comment: How do I do that? I thought CSS cascaded so that the bottom-most style is the one that is applied.  I didn't know I had to clear the default styles of elements.